# How to rewrite widget function with mixins Magento 2.1.1

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento-2.1.1, mixins

We have `swatch-renderer.js`

In this file there are some widgets.

```
....
    $.widget('mage.SwatchRenderer', {
....

    /**
     * @private
     */
    _init: function () {
        if (this.options.jsonConfig !== '' && this.options.jsonSwatchConfig !== '') {
            this._sortAttributes();
            this._RenderControls();
        } else {
            console.log('SwatchRenderer: No input data received');
        }
    },

    /**
     * @private
     */
    _sortAttributes: function () {
        this.options.jsonConfig.attributes = _.sortBy(this.options.jsonConfig.attributes, function (attribute) {
            return attribute.position;
        });
    },
```

I'd like to rewrite some of its functions.

**What is the proper way how to do it?**

Explanations in magento library are not actual anymore, they are linked on classes which are using another approach (I'm speaking about place-order.js / place-order-mixin.js). And described examples doesn't explain somehow how to rewrite widget functions.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
                'path/to/your/mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

path/to/your/mixin.js

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';

    return function (widget) {

        $.widget('mage.SwatchRenderer', widget, {
            _Rebuild: function () {
                console.log('Hello from rebuild', arguments);
                return this._super();
            }
        });

        return $.mage.SwatchRenderer;
    }
});
```

Comment: after 7 years your answer helps me again. thanks Max

Comment: when original name passing in widget it is not working but when passing our own custom widget and return same it is working.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: my answer is not using mixins. To my knowledge, mixins only work for methods rewrites and properties. In your case, it's pure JS being called directly outside of a method.

You can do it via a module.

In `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` you can add the following:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer':'Vendor_Module/js/swatch-renderer'
        }
    }
};
```

Then you can create the `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` file by copying the original `swatch-renderer.js` file and modify its content based on what you want to do.

Comment: **Raphael**, sorry for not-responding for long time. Had no free time. In other words there no proper way to rewrite widget methods? Only full complete rewrite? I mean that if magento update existing file - we will need to update our rewrite.

Comment: @zhartaunik it is totally possible to rewrite widget methods using mixins. The problem in your case is that the swatch-renderer file does not have any methods, it's one single script. Because of that we can't use mixins and thus have to go full rewrite.  AFAIK that's the only way to do it

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I have just been trying to do the same thing as you describe but continually getting `Uncaught TypeError: base is not a constructor` - any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: You should be able to rewrite `SwatchRenderer` widget with mixin because the function passed to `define` has at the end `return $.mage.SwatchRenderer;`. I don't know about the other widget defined in the same file `SwatchRendererTooltip`.

Comment: Here is example https://www.codedecorator.com/blog/how-to-rewrite-widget-function-with-mixins-magento-2/